# Join two tables in PostgreSQL in different schemas without schema's names

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, inner-join

How it's possible to join two tables in different schemas without the schema's name?

Consider two schemas, USERS with Person table and ANIMALS with Pet Table.
Person and Pet tables have the same column id_person.

If I run this query:

```
SELECT pet.name FROM person p
INNER JOIN pet a ON p.id_person = a.id_person
```

I get this error: "ERROR:  relation "person" does not exist".

I know that I can specify the schema for Person and Pet, and it's works, but in an other case I've seen a query like this work without schemas name.

I know also that the schemas have no views.

Thanks for your helping.

Comment: Follow the [search_path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thaks, it's work!

Comment: Why is it so difficult to specify the schema. While specifying the search path works it it borders on the edge to total failure.  Here the response you get likely comes from a second schema  because the table does not exist in the first schema. Then a system change comes along and a table with the same name but totally different structure is created in the first schema.

Comment: Well your query will now references the new table. If you are lucky this causes your process to abort, if unlucky it processed the wrong data.  It you specify the schema name, you still get the correct table, and no wonders *where does this data come from*?